# CSS - vendor prefixes don't validate

Tags: css, w3c-validation, vendor-prefix

How am I supposed to achieve valid CSS3 on [W3C's CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) if I use properties with vendor prefixes like `-webkit-border-radius` and `-moz-box-shadow`?

Comment: uh... those are not valid CSS... they're proprietary.

Comment: "Valid" CSS is overrated. Working CSS is much better. Especially since valid != working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the **Vendor Extensions** combo select **Warnings**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Vendor prefixes are **not** valid CSS, therefore it will not pass as valid in the W3C validator. In the future, when they won't be needed anymore, the normal CSS rules will pass as valid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to validate... for a client or a boss?

If not, I would say that validation is the goal... but only as a way to help you write good code and to catch simple errors from bad typing or bad memory.

If you need to do it (validate), either ignore the errors dealing with the prefixes or comment those out when you are validating.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do something with jQuery. Write your css code without css3 vendor prefixes and then [**this plugin**](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) can help you!!

Comment: I am not sure why this Answer got DownVote, +1ing this! Have a good one! `:)`